# Passing parameters to map function in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, parameter-passing

I am new to Hadoop. I want to access a command line argument from main function(Java program) inside the map function of the mapper class. Please suggest ways to do this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Hadoop 0.20](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/05/what%E2%80%99s-new-in-hadoop-core-020/), introduced new MR API, there is not much functionality difference between the new (o.a.h.mapreduce package) and old MR API (o.a.h.mapred) except that data can be pulled within the mappers and the reducers using the new API. What Arnon is mentioned is with the old API.

Check this [article](http://hadoop-tips.blogspot.com/2011/11/passing-parameters-to-mappers-and.html) for passing the parameters using the new and old API.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. It helped solve the problem.

Comment: BTW, I am the author of the blog :)

Comment: @PraveenSripati , Hadoop 0.20 is not existed [ 404 ], ,Please change it

Answer (score 15):

You can pass parameters by hanging them on the Configuration

```
 JobConf job = new JobConf(new Configuration(), TheJob.class);
 job.setLong("Param Name",longValue)
```

The Configuration class has few set methods (Long, Int, Strings etc.) so you can pass parameters of several types. In the map job you can get the configuration from the Context (getConfiguration)

Comment: Is it possible to pass parameters of ArrayList type?

Comment: @NiharSarangi No that way but you can pass an array of strings using the setStrings Method described here http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html#setStrings(java.lang.String, java.lang.String...)

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz +1 I always like answers that stand on their own (no dependence on external sites for information since links often break or content changes).

Answer (score 5):

In recent Hadoop (e.g. >=0.2 up to 2.4+) you would set this kind of options during the job configuration:

```java
conf = new JobConf(MyJarClass);
conf.set("myStringOption", "myStringValue");
conf.set("myIntOption", 42);
```

And retrieve those options in the `configure()` method ofmapper/reducer classes:

```
public static class MyMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<...> {

    Integer myIntegerOption;
    String myStringOption;

    @Override
    public void configure(JobConf job) {
        super.configure(job);
        myIntegerOption = job.getInt("myIntOption", -1); 
        // nb: last arg is the default value if option is not set
        myStringOption = job.get("myStringOption", "notSet");
    }

    @Override
    public void map(... key, ... value, 
                    OutputCollector<..> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        // here you can use the options in your processing
        processRecord(key, value, myIntOption, myStringOption);
    }

}
```

Note that `configure()` will be called once before any records are passed to the map or reduce.