# How to pass parameters for hadoop hbase mapper methods

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am using Hadoop Map Reduce to count things in our Hbase database.  I am using the `initTableMapperJob` method to perform my Hbase mapreduce job.

This code snippet below works but I need to pass in values so that I count only rows where something in the key is greater than X.  The [API docs](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableMapReduceUtil.html) don't show any other method I can use to pass in custom values.

```
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(tableName, scan, MyMapper.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class, job);
```

MyMapper.class extends TableMapper but I didn't find anything for that class either.

Ideally, I'd like to write a function like this:

```
@Override
public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable rowkey, Result columns, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // extract the ci as the key from the rowkey
    String pattern = "\\d*_(\\S*)_(\\d{10})";
    String ciname = null;
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    String strRowKey = Bytes.toString(rowkey.get());
    Matcher m = r.matcher(strRowKey);
    long ts = 0;

    // get parts of the rowkey
    ts = Long.valueOf(m.group(2)).longValue();
    ciname = m.group(1);

    // check the time here to see if we count it or not in the counts       
    if (ts > starttime) && (ts <= endtime) 
       context.write(new Text(ciname), ONE);
```

I need a way to pass in the starttime and endtime values into the mapper for the comparison test to see if we need to count the row or not.

Comment: Why not search for this. This for example shows how to pass parameters from Job to Mapper and Reducer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457183/passing-parameters-to-map-function-in-hadoop

Comment: @tsolakp, thx, I found that answer too but I kind of ignored it when I saw the age of the question/posting and it referencing hadoop 0.20.  I'll read it more closely to see if it helps me.

Comment: There is answer by oDDsKooL that applies to newer version of hadoop.